# LNK1561 in hand coded C++ MFC hello world with visual studio 2012 pro

Tags: visual-studio, mfc, linker-errors

After being away for a decade, I am using Jeff Prosie's Programing MFC to rebuild my understanding of MFC using visual studio 2012. His simple Hello World program generates a LNK 1561: entry point must be defined error. Since I have a global CWinApp declared, I do not understand this. All of the suggestions I saw cited a VS 2010 menu item that does not appear in VS 2012.Can anyone get me started (I don't want to use the MFC wizard yet).

Comment: "I want to hammer a nail in. I know I should use a hammer but I don't want to. Help me hammer my nail in without a hammer!"

Comment: True if you are hammering a nail, but if you are trying to understand a complex subject, a magnifying glass and ruler work better.

Answer (score 0):

If you "hand-crafted" a project, chances are that you haven't set all the settings correctly for an MFC program, including linking of the MFC libraries and setting the correct entry point.

I know you say that you don't want to use the MFC wizard, although I'm not sure *why* you don't... but the answer to that is **Use the MFC wizard**.

Comment: Thanks but I found the answer and it was in the settings: Linker/System was not set to Windows (/SUBSYSTEM:WINDOWS). The reason I don't want to use the wizard is that I am trying to refresh my knowledge of the basic essentials - something I can not do with wizard generated code, but I did use the wizard when I wrote MFC code ten years ago, but thanks for your advice.